# Toggle alert after success message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I toggle the following alert to be closed after 2 sec?

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    Success message
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following:

```
$('#alert').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Good luck!